# Dealing with sweat and earbuds

Tags: sweat

This might just be an idiosyncratic issue, but I'm a heavy sweater, and lately, it's been causing issues for earbud use on my runs. The sweat starts to accumulate in my ear, often making the earbuds keep slipping out and occasionally muffling the sound or shorting them out (that last is no real fun). I know that part of it is probably a matter of cheap earbuds, but the last time I spent more than $10 for earbuds, they lasted even less time than the dollar store ones, with the wire separating from the plug within months.

Comment: Maybe some neck headphones would be good for you. Not sure what the proper name is but you wear them around your neck and they're just little speakers.

Comment: Have you tried using the buds that curl around your ear?

Comment: @rrirower: I've used them in the past. I remember them having similar problems of falling out readily. I don't remember if I had the shock issue. I'll have to try that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So one suggestion I would have is trying bone conduction headphones. I have a pair I use for working out and they stay on well. They are also sweat resistant. I am not gonna recommend a specific pair cause that would be kinda against the stack exchange network protocol.

The issues I would say with bone conduction is that you can still hear everything around you. This is a double edged sword. I like that for biking, running, and traveling because I have full situational awareness. The bad news is you can hear everything around you unlike most headphones.